# Convert text to Uppercase while typing

Tags: java, netbeans, textfield

I have this JFrame with JTextField and I want to make it that each letter I type into it, be converted to uppercase automatically **WHILE** I'm typing in this JTextField.

I am using Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

```
class UpperCaseDocument extends PlainDocument {
  private boolean upperCase = true;

  public void setUpperCase(boolean flag) {
    upperCase = flag;
  }

  public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attSet)
      throws BadLocationException {
    if (upperCase)
      str = str.toUpperCase();
    super.insertString(offset, str, attSet);
  }

}


JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
UpperCaseDocument ucd = new UpperCaseDocument();
//Associates the editor with a text document. 
tf.setDocument(ucd);
```

Source: [Force JTextField to convert input to upper case with PlainDocument in Java](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing/JTextField/Force_JTextField_to_convert_input_to_upper_case_with_PlainDocument_in_Java.htm)